# python pandas - compare and add row to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe like below

```
ID     num
A032   [B001,B002,B003]
A052   [B002,B003,B005]
...
```

and get `A032 [B002,B005,B006]` this in to the dataframe so it would look like this

```
ID     num
A032   [B001,B002,B003,B005,B006]
A052   [B002,B003,B005]
...
```

So what I'm trying to do is to check whether it is already in the dataframe

add it in the `num` if there already is

or

add new row if there isn't the ID existing in the dataframe

Comment: A pandas dataframe is not the ideal struct for this operation. Apparently you just need a dictionary with the strings `A032` as key, and a set as value.

Comment: If I can't do it in dataframe than I guess I would have to start over with dictionary.
Thx for the advice